# What is the accurate configuration to inform the Zend framework about the new module?

Tags: php, zend-framework

So if you follow the Zend framework documentation to build a skeleton application, when you get to the part where you have to inform Zend of about the new module, the documentation provides this example:

```
return array(
     'modules' => array(
         'Application',
         'Album',                  // <-- Add this line
     ),
     'module_listener_options' => array(
         'config_glob_paths'    => array(
             'config/autoload/{{,*.}global,{,*.}local}.php',
         ),
         'module_paths' => array(
             './module',
             './vendor',
         ),
     ),
 );
```

If you look at the actual file it looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * If you need an environment-specific system or application configuration,
 * there is an example in the documentation
 * @see https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/advanced-config/#environment-specific-system-configuration
 * @see https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/advanced-config/#environment-specific-application-configuration
 */
return [
    // Retrieve list of modules used in this application.
    'modules' => require __DIR__ . '/modules.config.php',

    // These are various options for the listeners attached to the ModuleManager
    'module_listener_options' => [
        // This should be an array of paths in which modules reside.
        // If a string key is provided, the listener will consider that a module
        // namespace, the value of that key the specific path to that module's
        // Module class.
        'module_paths' => [
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ],

        // An array of paths from which to glob configuration files after
        // modules are loaded. These effectively override configuration
        // provided by modules themselves. Paths may use GLOB_BRACE notation.
        'config_glob_paths' => [
            realpath(__DIR__) . '/autoload/{{,*.}global,{,*.}local}.php',
        ],

        // Whether or not to enable a configuration cache.
        // If enabled, the merged configuration will be cached and used in
        // subsequent requests.
        'config_cache_enabled' => true,

        // The key used to create the configuration cache file name.
        'config_cache_key' => 'application.config.cache',

        // Whether or not to enable a module class map cache.
        // If enabled, creates a module class map cache which will be used
        // by in future requests, to reduce the autoloading process.
        'module_map_cache_enabled' => true,

        // The key used to create the class map cache file name.
        'module_map_cache_key' => 'application.module.cache',

        // The path in which to cache merged configuration.
        'cache_dir' => 'data/cache/',

        // Whether or not to enable modules dependency checking.
        // Enabled by default, prevents usage of modules that depend on other modules
        // that weren't loaded.
        // 'check_dependencies' => true,
    ],

    // Used to create an own service manager. May contain one or more child arrays.
    // 'service_listener_options' => [
    //     [
    //         'service_manager' => $stringServiceManagerName,
    //         'config_key'      => $stringConfigKey,
    //         'interface'       => $stringOptionalInterface,
    //         'method'          => $stringRequiredMethodName,
    //     ],
    // ],

    // Initial configuration with which to seed the ServiceManager.
    // Should be compatible with Zend\ServiceManager\Config.
    // 'service_manager' => [],
];
```

This is my guess:

```
return [
    // Retrieve list of modules used in this application.
    'modules' => require __DIR__ . '/modules.config.php',

    'modules' => [
        'Application',
        'Article',
    ],

    // These are various options for the listeners attached to the ModuleManager
    'module_listener_options' => [
        // This should be an array of paths in which modules reside.
        // If a string key is provided, the listener will consider that a module
        // namespace, the value of that key the specific path to that module's
        // Module class.
        'module_paths' => [
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ],
```

I ask because I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Could not find a valid ServiceManager for RoutePluginManager' in /Users/ldco2016/Projects/kbase/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/ServiceListener.php on line 202
( ! ) Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\Exception\RuntimeException: Could not find a valid ServiceManager for RoutePluginManager in /Users/ldco2016/Projects/kbase/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/ServiceListener.php on line 202
```

So I am wondering if the configuration for informing Zend about the new module is incorrect and that's why it can't find a valid ServiceManager or if, despite the fact that I added a classmap file in module/Article of:

```
return array();
```

do I still have to add a getAutoloaderConfig() { } and add it to composer.json file? So I did add a getAutoloaderConfig() {} and now I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (Application) could not be initialized.' in /Users/ldco2016/Projects/kbase/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php on line 203
( ! ) Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException: Module (Application) could not be initialized. in /Users/ldco2016/Projects/kbase/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php on line 203
```

I have pored over documentation and cannot find a straight answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused about what version of ZF and what version of the skeleton you are using...

In the current version (ZF3), the module config has been moved to a different file that is then included in the main one: [modules.config.php](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/config/modules.config.php).
That is where you stick your new module name.

As of ZF3, you do not need the `getAutoloaderConfig` method. Zend Autoload has been completely removed anyway, in favour of the Composer autoloader (PSR-0/PSR-4): [Composer autoload config](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/composer.json#L23). You need to add your own module in there, and then use the `composer dump-autoload` command to enable the autoloader.

Comment: Im thinking I have ZF3, but following 2.4 documentation.

Comment: No worries, they are pretty similar anyways. How far have you been now?

Comment: well, i created the zend 3 framework, but I was not sure what to do next, do I still build the folders same as the 2.4 version?